# SSIS Google Analytics - Dimension and Metrics Blank

Tags: google-analytics, ssis, google-analytics-api

I am trying to use the SSIS Google Analytics connector https://analyticssource.codeplex.com/

The problem I am running into is that the dimension and metric drop down menus are blank, as are the dimension and metric tabs.

I am able to log in successfully. It gives me the Access Token and I can see all the Accounts, Web Properties, and Profiles I am expecting to see.

This is a corporate account that is managed by IT, which may be affecting things.

I am able to run queries and see dimensions and metrics using Google Analytics query explorer, so I don't think it's a permisions issue. https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

I am on a Windows 7 machine using Visual Studio 2012.

[image: Blank Drop Down]
[image: Blank Tab]

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the dimension and metric xml files in down load section and point to these two files in your ssis componen.